# PEGAR DADOS DO FORM JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

Então queria fazer o seguinte tem um **form** que tem  vários campos input, então queria fazer o seguinte fazer um loop ou algo parecido para pegar os valores dos campos usando jquery ou js(puro).

Gostaria de saber uma forma de fazer isso

Comment: Tentou fazer algo? O que sabe de JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**JQuery**

```
// pega todos os input
var $inputs = $('form :input');

var values = {};
// percorre os inputs 
$inputs.each(function() {
    var name = this.name; // nome do input
    var value = $(this).val(); // valor do input
});
```

Comment: Obrigado funcionou